# String and StringBuilder return type in method

Tags: java

I have one doubt if I use return type as String then it stored in heap memory or not?

For example.

```
public String someName(){

return "Test String";

}



public StringBuilder someName(){
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hi from sb");
        return sb;

}
```

On above example we create two method 1. return String 2. return StringBuilder.

So my question is 1st method string is stored in heap or not ?

Comment: All objects are stored on heap, although in this case the String is contained in the string pool, but it's still a part of the heap.

Comment: Meanse if we use any datatype in return statement it will be stored in heap ? right ?

Comment: It means: if you are using **objects** they always reside on the heap.

Comment: I think string literals are are stroed in the string intern pool

Comment: Still, i am not getting My question is if I use String in return type so that string stored in heap or not ?

Comment: My question: have you tried even a **single** second to use google? This is explained **zillions** of times out there! Ever heard of **prior** research? http://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory

Comment: Every object exist in heap. Some exist in special part of heap like string pool which is cache for string literals. I am not sure what is confusing you.

Comment: @ GhostCat : ya I  tried but not found my question answer so i write here. any problem from your side? if you have then left this conversation why are you, patient ?

Comment: @ GhostCat :  thanks for this link : http://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory. now clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is a memory place where the methods and the local variables are stored. Heap is a memory place where the objects and its instance variable are stored.